# Is there a way to set attributes of an object from a json, ignoring unknown attributes?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actual, I have this:

```
      ip = HTTP.get("http://ip-api.com/json/24.48.0.1")
      if ip.code == 200
        Ipgeo.create(JSON.parse(ip.body).deep_symbolize_keys)
      end
```

I want to create the Ipgeo object from the json response of the http request. The http request has more attributes than my object, so the error raised is:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute
```

Is there a way that it works? Like create with a params for excluding unknown attributes? or filter my json with the know parameters for that object?

I want to skipt the process of:

```
ip = Ipgeo.new()
ip.country = JSON.parse(ip.body)["country"]
ip.lat = JSON.parse(ip.body)["lat"]
...

Or

ip = Ipgeo.create(
  country: JSON.parse(ip.body)["country"]
...
)
```

Comment: You should ask yourself if you actually trust the third party enough that you want to let them set any existing column in the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`column_names`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class) method in `ActiveRecord` it returns a list of column names (an array of strings) that a model contains. If you pass the result of this method to [`slice`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) you'll get only attributes that your model has.

```rb
Ipgeo.create(JSON.parse(ip.body).slice(*Ipgeo.column_names))
```

**UPD**

As @max mentioned in the comment, it's good to have a whitelist.

```rb
IPGEO_ATTRIBUTES = ['country', 'lat']
#...
Ipgeo.create(JSON.parse(ip.body).slice(*IPGEO_ATTRIBUTES))
```

Comment: While convenient this should be done with great care as you're giving yourself a mass assignment vulnerability. If possible use an explicit whitelist instead.

Comment: @max good point. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you both! It is a good point the whitelist, but I made the model based on the API response, so I don't care about what is setting. I think maybe could be a problem is the API response contains a field 'ID' and that crush with my db IDs, but for now there is no ID in the response.